# PC firefox play youtube video on samsung smart tv youtube app

Tags: firefox, video, android, youtube, smart-tv

From my android phone I can play any YouTube video on my Samsung Smart TV or my Chromecast.

I would like to play YouTube videos from my PC with Firefox on other smart devices, too.

Scenario: I browse on my PC in Firefox using YouTube. I find a great video and want to watch it on my smart TV. How can i do that with a simple click?

On android there is that play on other device button. I miss that on the PC YouTube website.

Answer (score 5):

Under following link are instructions how to connect to tv in menu connected TVs

https://www.youtube.com/pair 
or how to video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o8RHLLkjSQ

Goal is to add /pair the tv, adding it to your youtube account.

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: Matus: I paired my TV successfully, but the "cast" icon does not appear on the browser player.

Comment: this icons seems to missing when using Firefox (83.0 64-bit at the moment), but it works on Chrome. Why Google are so racist? The ~/pair link is now longer working, it leads to some help page where I meet the requirements, but still not working in Firefox